# Oracle code receiving error message, not sure how to fix

Tags: oracle

Not sure if I'm in the right place but below is code I'm working on and I'm receiving the error message:

OraOLEDB : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
OraOLEDB : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

I've tried everything I can think of to fix it and just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select xx.*,

  XX.TermCode
FROM(

Select *,

CASE WHEN ZZ.ACTC IS NULL AND ZZ.SATC IS NULL THEN NULL
 WHEN ZZ.ACTC IS NULL THEN ZZ.SATC
 WHEN ZZ.SATC IS NULL THEN ZZ.ACTC
 WHEN ZZ.SATC>=ZZ.ACTC THEN ZZ.SATC
 WHEN ZZ.ACTC>=ZZ.SATC THEN ZZ.ACTC
 ELSE NULL END "BEST"


FROM (

Select
   AA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY as "TermCode",
   BB.SPRIDEN_ID as "RNumber",
   BB.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME as "FirstName",
   BB.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME as "LastName",
   CC.SPBPERS_SEX as "Gender",
   CC.SPBPERS_ETHN_CDE as "Ethnicity",

(Select GG.GORRACE_DESC from GENERAL.GORRACE GG, GENERAL.GORPRAC GE
    where GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = '1'
    and GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = GG.GORRACE_RACE_CDE
    AND AA.SARADAP_PIDM = GE.GORPRAC_PIDM) "Race1",

(Select GG.GORRACE_DESC from GENERAL.GORRACE GG, GENERAL.GORPRAC GE
    where GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = '2'
    and GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = GG.GORRACE_RACE_CDE
    AND AA.SARADAP_PIDM = GE.GORPRAC_PIDM) "Race2",

(Select GG.GORRACE_DESC from GENERAL.GORRACE GG, GENERAL.GORPRAC GE
    where GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = '3'
    and GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = GG.GORRACE_RACE_CDE
    AND AA.SARADAP_PIDM = GE.GORPRAC_PIDM) "Race3",

(Select GG.GORRACE_DESC from GENERAL.GORRACE GG, GENERAL.GORPRAC GE
    where GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = '4'
    and GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = GG.GORRACE_RACE_CDE
    AND AA.SARADAP_PIDM = GE.GORPRAC_PIDM) "Race4",

(Select GG.GORRACE_DESC from GENERAL.GORRACE GG, GENERAL.GORPRAC GE
    where GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = '5'
    and GE.GORPRAC_RACE_CDE = GG.GORRACE_RACE_CDE
    AND AA.SARADAP_PIDM = GE.GORPRAC_PIDM) "Race5",

    DD.STVLGCY_DESC as "Legacy",
    CC.SPBPERS_CITZ_CODE as "Citizenship",
    AA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE as "AdmitType",
    AA.SARADAP_STYP_CODE as "SType",
    AA.SARADAP_APST_CODE as "AppStatus",
    AA.SARADAP_APST_DATE as "AppDate",
    EE.SARAPPD_APDC_CODE as "Decision",
    EE.SARAPPD_APDC_DATE as "Date",
    AA.SARADAP_RECR_CODE as "Recruiter",
    FF.STVSBGI_DESC as "HighSchool",
    LL.SOBSBGI_CITY as "City",
    LL.SOBSBGI_STAT_CODE as "State",
    MM.SORHSCH_CLASS_RANK as "Rank",
    MM.SORHSCH_CLASS_SIZE as "Size",

(select PA.SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA
     from SATURN.SPRTELE PA
    where PA.SPRTELE_TELE_CODE ='PR'
          and AA.SARADAP_PIDM = PA.SPRTELE_PIDM
          and PA.SPRTELE_STATUS_IND IS NULL
          and PA.SPRTELE_PRIMARY_IND ='Y') "PR_AreaCode",

(select PN.SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER
     from SATURN.SPRTELE PN
    where PN.SPRTELE_TELE_CODE ='PR'
          and AA.SARADAP_PIDM = PN.SPRTELE_PIDM
          and PN.SPRTELE_STATUS_IND IS NULL
          and PN.SPRTELE_PRIMARY_IND ='Y') "PR_Phone",

(select SA.SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA
     from SATURN.SPRTELE SA
    where SA.SPRTELE_TELE_CODE ='SC'
          and AA.SARADAP_PIDM = SA.SPRTELE_PIDM
          and SA.SPRTELE_STATUS_IND IS NULL) "SC_AreaCode",

(select SP.SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER
     from SATURN.SPRTELE SP
    where SP.SPRTELE_TELE_CODE ='SC'
          and AA.SARADAP_PIDM = SP.SPRTELE_PIDM
          and SP.SPRTELE_STATUS_IND IS NULL) "SC_Phone",

(select pp.GOREMAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS
     from GENERAL.GOREMAL pp
    where pp.GOREMAL_STATUS_IND ='A'
          and AA.SARADAP_PIDM = pp.GOREMAL_PIDM
          and pp.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE ='HOME') "Email",

MJ.STVMAJR_DESC as "Major",

(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='APTS')"APTS",
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='ARNK')"ARNK",
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where
 TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='RGPA')"RGPA",
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_DATE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='RGPA')"RGPAdate",
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='S01')+
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='S02')"SATC",
(select max(TT.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) from SATURN.SORTEST TT where 
TT.SORTEST_PIDM=AA.SARADAP_PIDM and TT.SORTEST_TESC_CODE ='A05')"ACT",

SS.ACTC




from    SATURN.SARADAP AA,
    SATURN.SPRIDEN BB,
    SATURN.STVSBGI FF,
    SATURN.SOBSBGI LL,
    SATURN.SORHSCH MM,
    SATURN.SPBPERS CC,
    SATURN.STVLGCY DD,
SATURN.STVMAJR MJ,
SATURN.SARAPPD EE,

(SELECT SS.SORTEST_PIDM, MAX(SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE) "SCORE", AA.SARADAP_PIDM,
CASE when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE IS NULL AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN NULL
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '09' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '400'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '10' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '500'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '11' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '550'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '12' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '590'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '13' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '640'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '14' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '690'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '15' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '740'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '16' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '790'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '17' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '830'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '18' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '870'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '19' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '910'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '20' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '950'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '21' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '990'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '22' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1030'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '23' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1070'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '24' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1110'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '25' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1140'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '26' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1180'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '27' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1220'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '28' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1260'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '29' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1300'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '30' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1340'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '31' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1380'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '32' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1420'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '33' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1470'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '34' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1520'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '35' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1550'
 when SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE = '36' AND SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE = 'A05' THEN '1600'
 ELSE NULL END FROM SATURN.SORTEST SS, SATURN.SARADAP AA WHERE 
AA.SARADAP_PIDM=SS.SORTEST_PIDM
 GROUP BY SS.SORTEST_PIDM, AA.SARADAP_PIDM, SS.SORTEST_TEST_SCORE, 
SS.SORTEST_TESC_CODE) "ACTC"


where AA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY = '201409'
and   AA.SARADAP_PIDM=BB.SPRIDEN_PIDM
and   AA.SARADAP_PIDM=CC.SPBPERS_PIDM
and   CC.SPBPERS_LGCY_CODE=DD.STVLGCY_CODE
and   AA.SARADAP_PIDM=EE.SARAPPD_PIDM
and   AA.SARADAP_PIDM=MM.SORHSCH_PIDM
and   LL.SOBSBGI_SBGI_CODE = MM.SORHSCH_SBGI_CODE
and   AA.SARADAP_MAJR_CODE_1 = MJ.STVMAJR_CODE
AND   AA.SARADAP_STYP_CODE = 'N'
AND   AA.SARADAP_COLL_CODE_1 = 'AS'

group by AA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY,
     BB.SPRIDEN_ID,
     BB.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME,
     BB.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,
     CC.SPBPERS_SEX,
     CC.SPBPERS_ETHN_CDE,
     AA.SARADAP_PIDM,
     DD.STVLGCY_DESC,
     CC.SPBPERS_CITZ_CODE,
     AA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE,
     AA.SARADAP_STYP_CODE,
     AA.SARADAP_APST_CODE,
     AA.SARADAP_APST_DATE,
     EE.SARAPPD_APDC_CODE,
     EE.SARAPPD_APDC_DATE,
     AA.SARADAP_RECR_CODE,
     FF.STVSBGI_DESC,
     LL.SOBSBGI_CITY,
     LL.SOBSBGI_STAT_CODE,
     MM.SORHSCH_CLASS_RANK,
     MM.SORHSCH_CLASS_SIZE,
     MJ.STVMAJR_DESC


)ZZ

)XX

Where xx.APTS >= '27' 
and   (xx.SATC >= '1340' or xx.ACT >='30')

Order by xx.LastName, xx.FirstName
```

Comment: Please reduce this to the smallest possible bit of SQL that still produces this error.  In doing so, you'll probably discover the problem yourself, but if you don't I'm sure we can help then.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to figure out with your massive wall of SQL (please whittle this down to the smallest example next time), but I'm guessing that this line:

```
Select *,
```

should be:

```
Select ZZ.*,
```

You can't in general select columns after an unqualified `*`...eg. even the following fails:

```
SELECT *, dummy FROM DUAL;
```

Whereas this is ok:

```
SELECT d.*, dummy FROM DUAL d;
```